# Select All from table but ignore last N Records

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008, sequelize.js

Currently I am using Sequelize to get paginated records from MSSQL. Below is my query,

```
Blog.findAll({
    offset: 10,
    limit: 5
});
```

**Scenario:**

Suppose if there are 100 records and data processing has to happen only between first sorted 95 records along with pagination in scene. How can I do that?

**Requirement Steps:**

Need Sequelize version for query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * 
FROM 
(SELECT TOP 5 * 
    FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [id]) as row_num, *  
        FROM [sheet1$] AS [sheet1$] WHERE id < (max(id) - N)) AS [sheet1$] 
        WHERE row_num > 370293) AS [sheet1$]
```

**OR**

```
Blog.findAll({
    offset: 10,
    limit: 5,
    where: {
        [sequelize.op.lt] : {id : max(id) - N} 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[findAndCountAll][1]` and then `[limit][1]` to {size}-N

Comment: I am trying to do it in 1 query using Sequelize. Using Raw query it seems quite clear.